# Audio post format with Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: posts, post-formats, audio

I am using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin to create custom fields for post formats. I have a field that only displays when the audio post format is selected. This is a text filed where the user places a url from a soundcloud audio file, for example and then the the audio file should show on the front end of the post. However, I am having issues making this work. I have done the same process for the video post format and its working properly, however for audio files I am not having any luck so far.

The field I have created has the name of audio_post_format_url.

And the code bellow gets the value of that field and echoes it:

```
                $audio = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'audio_post_format_url', true );
                echo wp_oembed_get( $audio );
```

But at the moment nothing gets echoed.. what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Advanced Custom Field plugin uses [`get_field()`](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) to retrieve values.

Your code should be something like:

```
$audio = get_field('audio_post_format_url', $post->ID); 
var_dump( $audio ); # To make sure you're retrieving the right value
echo wp_oembed_get( $audio );
```

Note that `get_field()` does not need a second parameter, it will take the current post ID if omitted.

If `var_dump( $audio )` displays `false`, then you should check your ACF key.

Comment: var_dump displays the url that has been added to the field audio_post_format_url. But the echo wp_oembed_get( $audio ); doesnt echo anything.

Comment: Is it something to to with audio files? because I have exactly the same set up for video urls for the video post format and it works just fine..

Comment: The url I was using was not working at all. I have tried another url to an audio file on soundcloud and it is working now. However, sometimes it doesn't show anything and only after I force a cache refresh (ctrl - f5) I get it to show.. Why would that be?